# PPO on Unity ML Agents, how to discourage truck driving backwards?

Tags: reinforcement-learning

In Vector3 (x,y,z) I have access to current road direction (unit vector), velocity, nearest point on road, vectors at whatever offset from the truck's current position I want, etc.

How can I discourage it from driving in reverse?